# jQuery Accessing a field in form created dynamically

Tags: jquery

I create dyamically several forms like this

```
<form id="form1".....>
    ...
    <input type="submit" ...
    <div id="output1"><!--Here I want to show a message--></div>
</form>
<form id="form2".....>
...
    <input type="submit" ...
    <div id="output2"><!--Here I want to show a message--></div>
</form>
<form id="form3".....>
...
    <input type="submit" ...
    <div id="output3"><!--Here I want to show a message--></div>
</form>
<form id="form4".....>
    <input type="submit" ...
    <div id="output4"><!--Here I want to show a message--></div>
</form>
...


jQuery(function($) {
    $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
    $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            success: function(data, status) {
                $("#output").text("My Success Message");
                //How can I  select the correct id for this output?

            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And I need to set a message text into  the form submited with Ajax. 
$("#output").text("My Success Message");
I don´t know how to select output div for form submited!
How Can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it created dynamically by server side code like PHP or is it created client side with Javascript?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ Look there. It has your answer probably.

Comment: I create this forms with Twig and Symfony, and when i submit one form i can´t access to this div element $('#output').html("<b>Message</b>");
$('#output').css("color","red");

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("#output").text("My Success Message");
```

to

```
$form.find('[id^="output"]').text("My Success Message");
```

Comment: Yes, but find('.your-class') where '.your-class' it's not the same in each div. <div id="output1"> ...<div id="output n"> it has an iterator, and my doubt is how access to this exactly element in each form

Comment: Sorry, but It doesn´t work. I can't access or find to "output" because this item is called "outputn" where n is 1..n. Thanks for your help